# Keep struct intact in case of JSON unmarshal error

Tags: json, go

In case there is an error in unmarshalling JSON,  Go's `json.Unmarshal` returns a partially modified struct. Is there a way to ensure that the object remains intact in case of an error?

For example, in the following code ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MPCji1N98fi)):

```
type myStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    me := &myStruct{
        Name: "Alex",
        Age:  38,
    }
    data := []byte(`{"Name":"Bob", "Age": true}`)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, me)
    
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(me)
}
```

changes the `me` struct to `{Bob 38}`, while I would like it to stay `{ALex 38}`. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2):

using reflection you could dig the pointer to make a new value of the underlying struct, pass that to json.Unmarshal, if that works, replace the value of the original pointer to the newly decoded struct.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    me := &myStruct{
        Name: "Alex",
        Age:  38,
    }
    data := []byte(`{"Name":"Bob", "Age": true}`)
    err := unmarshal(data, me)

    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(me)
}

func unmarshal(data []byte, dst interface{}) error {

    typ := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem().Type()
    tmp := reflect.New(typ)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, tmp.Interface())
    if err == nil {
        reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem().Set(tmp.Elem())
    }
    return err
}
```

outputs:

```sh
json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field myStruct.Age of type int
&{Alex 38}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HjTEzTfdchx

https://play.golang.org/p/aia-LHIOB2R